# Best way to import CSV with 1M+ rows?

Tags: mysql

I am turning to you all for help after having struggled to import a CSV file with more than 1 million rows into my local MySQL server (running under Windows 10). I've tried `mysqlimport`, phpMyadmin and now I'm using the MySQL Workbench. The process has been running for over 15 minutes now and as far as I can tell, it's only managed to push ~55K rows.

What is the best way to accomplish this task quickly?

And while we're on the subject, earlier I made a database dump to an .sql file of around 1.5G, which I then tried to import into the production server. The dump is ~14M rows and so far I've only gotten 6M in after more than 5 hours.

Bottom line is, what could be set up wrongly on both servers for the import and export processes to take so long?

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` query is the fastest method. Indices, foreign keys, check constraints and triggers may decrease performance - sometimes dramatically.

Comment: That's definitely slow. Do the tables have lots of indexes defined? That would slow down inserts, but still hours and hours is an unreasonable amount of time. `LOAD DATA INFILE` is typically the fastest way to import a CSV.

Comment: Are you loading into a table that already has data?  Or into an empty table?

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE definitely did the trick. Thank you both!